# Close bootstrap dropdown on click same link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I've got a bootstrap 3 drop down and it should close when the user is clicking on the same link again.

Here's my html:

```
<li class="dropdown menu-karriere">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="asd">
  Karriere <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-lvl="0">
    <li class="menu-ausbildung"><a href="asd">Ausbildung</a></li>
    <li class="menu-geselle"><a href="asd">Geselle</a></li>
    <li class="menu-meister"><a href="asd">Meister</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

If I click on the `a.dropdown-toggle` the drop down opens - which is correct. If I click the same link again, the drop down doesn't close.

Can anybody help me with that?

I couldn't find something on SO or anywhere else.

Thanks.

Comment: if i remove data-target it will work as desired. Is that troubling you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. It will give you desired result.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Karriere
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Ausbildung</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Geselle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Meister</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `data-target="#"` which prevents it closing:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown menu-karriere">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="asd">
  Karriere <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-lvl="0">
    <li class="menu-ausbildung"><a href="asd">Ausbildung</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-geselle"><a href="asd">Geselle</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-meister"><a href="asd">Meister</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```